# Aveilus and burial for kohanim and levi'im

Tags: kohen-priest, mourning-aveilus, funeral-burial-levaya, levites-leviyim, taharat-hametim

Are there any special considerations for the tahara, burial, and/or aveilus for kohanim or levi'im who have passed away?

We should live to see the days of Moshiach.

Comment: I thought you meant processing the bodies of kohanim, but the answer understood it to mean kohanim processing bodies. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

**Burial:**

1. The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 191:1 [סימן קצט - דין הקבורה ובית הקברות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0198_L2) does mention that in some areas only the Cohanim and firstborns were buried in coffins.
   Seems that there is a tradition that some people are more equal than others when it comes to burial.

> יֵשׁ עוֹד מְקוֹמוֹת שֶׁקּוֹבְרִין שְׁאָר מֵתִים כָּךְ בְּלֹא אָרוֹן, וְרַק לְכֹהֲנִים וּבְכוֹרִים שֶׁהֵם חֲשׁוּבִים, עוֹשִׂים אָרוֹן.‏

2. The custom is to bury Cohanim - and if possible their relatives - near the edge, so that their graves can be visited by Cohanim. (Since Cohanim may not come within 4 Amos of a grave - אָסוּר לַכֹּהֵן לִקָּרֵב בְּתוֹךְ אַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת שֶׁל מֵת אוֹ שֶׁל קֶבֶר. וְדַוְקָא כְּשֶׁהַמֵּת מֻנָּח בִּמְקוֹם קְבִיעָתוֹ. Source: KSA 202:8 [סימן רב - הלכות טמאת כהן](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0201_L2))
   Can't find a direct source for this custom, but the Kitzur Yalkut Yosef refers to it in 57:2 [סימן נז - דין אזהרת טומאת כהן](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_66.html#HtmpReportNum0055_L2) when he says that if a Cohen was not buried near the fence, he need not be moved to the fence.

> כהנים שנקברו בתוך בית הקברות, ולא עשו להם קברים בפני עצמם, אין בכך כלום, והיינו שאין צריך להעבירם לקבר סמוך לגדר. ‏